# How to prove in a simple way $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{!n}{n!} =\frac{1}{e} $?

Tags: limits

While studying derangements, I've found on the internet the following relation : $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{!n}{n!} =\frac{1}{e} \approx 0.3679\ldots.$$

This relation really intrigues me and I would like to know how to prove it.

In the detail,I came across the above limit reading [this article](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Derangement) from AOPS site . In the article it is said  that the above limit can be noted given the recurrence  $!n=n\cdot!(n-1)+(-1)^{n}$ .

Sadly I can't note that.

Anyway I've tried to do something.

Given the following relation $ !n = n! \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ I have that $ \cfrac{!n}{n!}=\sum_{k=0}^n \cfrac {(-1)^k}{k!} $  .

Now the right hand side of the last equality is interesting because it can be written as $$\sum_{k=0}^n \cfrac {1}{k!} \cdot (-1)^k $$ and I know that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \cfrac {1}{k!} =e $$ but now I am left with the trouble of the $(-1)^k$ factor which I don't know how to handle.

Comment: In general, we have that
$$e^x=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!} $$
from which it follows.

Comment: What is !n ?  Never saw this before.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well-known that $$e^x = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
Now set $x = -1$, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

$\exp(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ **for all** $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Hence, for $x=-1$, we have $\exp(-1) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}= \frac1e$.

$D_n = n! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k!}$ so $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{D_n}{n!} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}= \frac1e$.

Comment: $\lim_n\to \infty \sum_{k=0}^n \cfrac{1}{k!} $doesn't equal $e$ ?I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the hard way if you don't know the gamma function:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{!n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\Gamma(n+1,-1)}{e}}{\Gamma(n+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1,-1)}{e\Gamma(n+1)}=\frac{1}{e}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1,-1)}{\Gamma(n+1)}$$

---

With $\Gamma(x)$ is the gamma function and $\Gamma(s,x)$ is the incomplete gamma function

Comment: Hmm...Can you give me some link for gamma function,so I can learn it ? Thanks for your answer,I like to have multiple approaches on one problem.

Comment: @Mr.Y I learned it at university, but wikipedia gives a ery good explanation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Answer (score 1):

Since, by definition, $!n = n! \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac {(-1)^k} {k!}$, it is easy to obtain

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{!n}{n!} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^k} {k!},$$

which is $\frac {1} {e}$.

The more intriguing is the equality in the article that you referred to

$$!n = \left \lfloor \frac {n!} {e} + \frac {1} {2} \right \rfloor,$$

and this is provable by induction on $n$ in the recurrence relation given for $!n$.